# Magento 2 - Full Width Section

Tags: magento2, layout, layout-update

If I need to add a new full width section between the main element and the footer element, is there a way to declare something in the theme's default.xml that places it before or after a container?

Comment: Try with CSS , that's simplest way

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Myvendor\Mymodule\Block\Myblock" name="unique_name" template="Myvendor_Mymodule::mysection.phtml" after="-" />
</referenceContainer>
```

Or

```
<referenceContainer name="after.body.end">
            <block class="Myvendor\Mymodule\Block\Myblock" name="unique_name" template="Myvendor_Mymodule::mysection.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
```

You can use css for custom styles.
Hope this helps.